# how to load 2 related datasets together? (i.e posts and comments)

Tags: sql, postgresql, node-postgres

I'm fairly new to pg and trying to figure out what the best approach is to loading a set of posts and their associated comments together.

For example:
I'm trying to fetch a 10 posts and comments associated with all those posts, like facebooks wall where you see a feed of posts and comments loaded on the same page. My Schema looks something like this:

```
Posts
--------
id  -  author   -  description  -  date   -  commentCount 

Comments
-------
id  -   post_id  -  author  -  description   -   date
```

I tried to load both posts and comments on the same postgres function doing the follow:

```
select *
from posts
LEFT join comments on posts.id = comments.post_id
```

unfortunately it duplicated the posts N times where comment exists, where N is the number of comments a post has. **However, the first solution is that I can always filter it out in Node after fetching the data**

Also when I try to use group by posts.id (to make it easier to traverse in node) I get the following error:

```
column "comments.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
```

**The second** thing I can try is to send an array of post_ids I want to load and have pg_function load and send them back, but I can't quite the query right:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "getPosts"(postIds int[])
  RETURNS text AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
    RETURN (
        SELECT * 
        FROM Comments
        WHERE Comments.id = postIds[0]
    );
END;$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
```

to call it:

```
SELECT n FROM "public"."getPosts"(array[38]) As n;
```

However, even when trying to get value from one index I get the following error:

```
ERROR:  subquery must return only one column
LINE 1: SELECT (
               ^
QUERY:  SELECT (
        SELECT * 
        FROM Comments
        WHERE Comments.id = 38
    )
```

Finally, the **last solution** is to simple make N seperate calls of postgres, where N is the number of posts with comments, so if I have 5 posts with comments I make 5 calls to postgres with post_id and select from Comments table.

I'm really not sure what to do here, any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: The first solution is the simplest and fastest. The other will need two queries and two trips to the server. About _duplicated_ posts that is the way it is with relational databases and it is a "problem" better dealt with in the presentation layer.

Comment: are you using only the sql?

Comment: im using postgres with node

Comment: @ClodoaldoNeto is there anyway to use group by without having that aggregate error show up?

Comment: Would you like to have an array of records for each post?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To have all comments as an array of records for each post:

```
select
    p.id, p.title, p.content, p.author,
    array_agg(c) as comments
from
    posts p
    left join
    comments c on p.id = c.post_id
group by 1, 2, 3, 4
```

Or one array for each comment column:

```
select
    p.id, p.title, p.content, p.author,
    array_agg(c.author) as comment_author,
    array_agg(c.content) as comment_content
from
    posts p
    left join
    comments c on p.id = c.post_id
group by 1, 2, 3, 4
```